# Kendo Grid Child -> using CRUD toolbar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

My problem is that I Have Hierarchical grid (Master and Child) let say I Have a Department Grid it contains List of Employee Grid, and they both use same datasource.
Here's my GridChild Code:

```
function detailInit (e){
    var msterRow =  e.sender.items().index(e.masterRow).toString();
    var grid = $("<div id='childGrid"+msterRow+"' 
              class=childGrid'/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    data: e.data.DeptEmployees,
    schema: {
        model: {  fields: { foo: {--skip--}, bar: {--skip--} } }
    },
    toolbar: ["create", "cancel", "save"],
    editable: "popup",
    columns: [ --skip--]
    save: function(e){
        ajaxUpdateDepartment(msterRow, this.dataSource.data());
    }
})
```

As you can see i use `data: e.data.DeptEmployees,` as child data source to fetch data.
Now I'm stacked in how can I update the child data source?

> What I have Tried:
>
> - I add child's `dataSource.transport` for updates, **but** my child grid keeps on loading.
> - So I end up configuring the `save: function (e)` and simply send all data source of the current child **but** popup editor didn't close at all. And I'm having difficulty to refresh the child data source.
> - I also attempt to convert my Master and Child Grid to ASP Razor **but** there was no definite example if how could I handle it in back end, and also my child grid contains drop down grid, so that would be a big re-do. And I also don't know if how can I pass customize parameter through it

I am desperate, I can't find any working reference except [this one](http://jsbin.com/voyik/1/edit?html,output). but it's using odata, and **I dont have child id** to use as reference, since I am only using list which I retrieve in a user event.

Please help :'( I'm taking too much time for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define a transport properties, in order to fetch data from master, I only need to define the data and convert that to Jason.

take a look of these code:

```
function detailInit (e){
    var msterRow =  e.sender.items().index(e.masterRow).toString();
    var grid = $("<div id='childGrid"+msterRow+"' 
              class=childGrid'/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    //data: e.data.ChildDetails,
    transport: {
         read: function (o) {
               console.log("child read");
               var data = e.data.ChildDetails.toJSON();
               o.success(data);
         },
         update: function (o) {
               console.log("child update");
               var data = o.data,
               arentItem = findByID(data.id);
               for (var field in data) {
                      if(!(field.indexOf("_") === 0)){
                           arentItem[field] = data[field];
                       }
                }
               e.data.dirty = true;
               saveChild(record, "@suffix", msterRow, "update");
               o.success();
          },
          destroy: function (o) {
               var parentItem = findByID(o.data.id);
               preventBinding = true;
               e.data.ChildDetails.results.remove(parentItem);
               o.success();
               saveChild(record, "@suffix", msterRow, "destroy");
          },
          create: function (o) {
                console.log("child create");
                var record = o.data;
                record.id = index;
                index++;
                saveChild(record, "@suffix", msterRow, "create");
                o.success(record);
           }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {  fields: { foo: {--skip--}, bar: {--skip--} } }
    },
    toolbar: ["create", "cancel", "save"],
    editable: "popup",
    columns: [ --skip--]
}
```

[Here's the working dojo snippet](http://dojo.telerik.com/IYAdU/2)